# Weak convergence in $L^{∞}[0,1]$ implies strong convergence in $L^{p}[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, banach-spaces, banach-algebras

I'm trying to solve an exercise in Rudin's Functional Analysis. It is the problem 19 in Chapter 11.

The problem is:

If $f_n\in L^{∞}[0,1]$ and converges to $0$ in the weak topology of $L^{∞}[0,1]$, then $\int_0^1|f_n|^p\to 0$ for any $p\in (0,∞)$.

I have tried to use Gelfand Transform that Rudin mentioned in 11.13(f), which maps $L^{∞}[0,1]$ isometrically to $C(\Delta)$ as Banach Spaces, where $\Delta$ is the maximal ideal space. This approach seems to be hopeful because continuous functions are good, but I failed despite a few hours effort.

Another trial is to solve this just for p=2, but I did not proceed any more, too.

I think the conclusion of this problem is very powerful so I want to know how to solve it very much. So please tell me anything if you have an idea or some relative materials, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me try $p=2$: Recall that the Gelfand Transform $f \mapsto \hat{f}$ is an isometric isomorphism onto $C(\Delta)$ and that there is a regular Borel measure $\mu$ on $\Delta$ with $\int_0^1 f dx = \int_\Delta \hat{f} d \mu$ $(f \in L^\infty[0,1])$. Setting $h(z)=|z|^2$ we have
$$
\forall \varphi \in \Delta: ~ |\hat{f}|^2(\varphi)= h\circ \hat{f}(\varphi)=h(\varphi(f))=\varphi(f)\overline{\varphi(f)}=\varphi(|f|^2)= \widehat{|f|^2}(\varphi),
$$
hence $|\hat{f}|^2=\widehat{|f|^2}$. Since $(f_n)$ is weakly convergent to $0$ it is bounded in $L^\infty([0,1])$, so $(\widehat{f_n})$ is pointwise convergent to $0$ in $\Delta$ and bounded in $C(\Delta)$. Hence $(\widehat{|f_n|^2})=(|\widehat{f_n}|^2)$ is pointwise convergent to $0$ and bounded. By LDCT
$$
\int_0^1 |f_n|^2 dx =\int_\Delta \widehat{|f_n|^2} d \mu =\int_\Delta |\widehat{f_n}|^2 d \mu \to 0 \quad (n\to \infty).
$$
If all above is correct (please check) the advantage of switching to $C(\Delta)$ is that (in contrast to $L^\infty[0,1]$) pointwise convergence to $0$ is easy to see.

Edit on account of Ryszard Szwarc' comment: With an analog calculation one gets $|\hat{f}|^{2m}=\widehat{|f|^{2m}}$ and $\int_0^1 |f_n|^{2m} dx \to 0$ for each $m \in \mathbb{N}$. If $p >0$ is given choose $m$ such that $2m \ge p$.
Then
$$
(\int_0^1 |f_n|^p dx)^{1/p} \le (\int_0^1 |f_n|^{2m} dx)^{1/(2m)} \to 0 \quad (n \to \infty).
$$

Comment: It suffices to consider $p=2n$ as the function $p\mapsto (\int_0^1|f|^p\,dx )^{1/p}$  is increasing.  Does it help ?

Comment: @Ryszard Szwarc Yes, good idea. I will edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: Oh, Thank you very much! I did not realize the boundness of f_n when I was trying, haha. Thank you again!

Comment: @北方火柴 If my answer was helpful to you, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: @Gerd  Apologize for not have done this. This my first asking so I did not know I could accept one.